# Input stream corruption android

Tags: android, assets

I'm working on an app in Android Studio, and I have a file in the assets folder. Though it doesn't have a path and I need a File object to be created from it, I've written this code:

```
InputStream asset = assetManager.open("databases/file.txt");
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(asset));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line, result;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
                result = sb.toString();
                byte[] resultToBytes = result.getBytes();
                File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath(),"tmp");
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                fileOutputStream.write(resultToBytes);
                fileOutputStream.close();
```

When I pull the file back to the computer, I find it's corrupted, or simply different from the original, also in the size. When am I getting wrong?

Comment: Did you try to set the charset? `getBytes( "UTF-8" )`

Comment: Tried right now.. doesn't work

Comment: Is your file in `UTF-8`? )

Comment: Ok, I discovered it isn't. It's a database file that I want to open with SQLiteDatabase.open (). If I try to open in directly from the sdcard, it works, so I guess it's the inputstream that doesn't work. I also tried with different files, but they always get corrupted at the same point. What's wrong?